# How do you describe when the hem of shirt is coming out from inside the pants?

Tags: phrase-request

When you wear a shirt, you tuck your shirt in your pants. But you move violently and one part of the shirt's hem creeps out from the pants and looks very untidy.

How do you describe the untidy shirt? The goal is to make him noticed and let him tuck the shirt's hem back in again. What I can think of is sentences such as your shirt came out, your shirt is untidy, etc. How do you usually say?

Comment: I see no mention yet on this page of what I'd consider by far the most common phrasing associated with this - [*Your shirt (tail) is **hanging out!***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shirt+is+hanging+out%22) Often accompanied by the imperative instruction ***Tuck it in**!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all verbs that are used for putting together clothing have an opposite verb with the prefix **un-**. Examples include **buckle/unbuckle**, **zip/unzip**, **tie/untie**, **button/unbutton**, and **tuck/untuck**.

Many of these verbs come as *phrasal verbs* with an accompanying preposition (e.g., **to tuck in**). The opposite **un-** verb does *not* use a preposition. Examples:

> **Button up** your coat. **Unbutton** your coat.
>
> Your fly is **zipped up**.  Your fly is **unzipped**.
>
> Your shirt is **tucked in**. Your shirt is **untucked**.

If you want to emphasize that the **un-** is something that happened by accident, then you can use the auxiliary verb **to come** or **to become** (using **come** sounds more idiomatic to me as an American English speaker). For example:

> Use a double knot or your shoes **will come untied**.
>
> Your shirt **has come untucked**.

If you say, "Your shirt **is untucked**," then this includes the possibilities that he never tucked it in the first place or that he deliberately pulled it out.  Using, "Your shirt has come untucked," says that you believe this happened spontaneously without him noticing.

Finally, a notable exception to this pattern is the phrasal verb **to put on**, which has the opposite **to take off** (*unput* is not correct).

> **Put on** your sweater. **Take off** your sweater.